# Showing INSERT and UPDATE statements for Rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I apparently haven't set up my associations properly; records aren't being saved out to where I thought they would be. Checking the output on the Rails server (`rails s`), I see lots of `SELECT` statements but no `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements.

Is there a way to view these types of queries with the rails server? Ideally I would like a solution that doesn't involve installing third party components... but if that is the only way, I might consider it after I throw a tantrum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did not change your configuration, all SQL statements appear in your server console by default.

3 things you can do:

**1-** You can check your config/environmets/development.rb file if there is a `config.log_level` statement. And eventually set it to `:debug`:

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

**2-** Also be sure your rails server runs in development, you can see that in the first lines in the console, or add `RAILS_ENV=development` in your `rails s` command

**3-** Place some were in your code (preferably in top of an entry function of your controller) `User.first.touch` (or using any other model of your choice) this is to confirm the UPDATE statement is correctly appearing in the logs